# Sensor power/notification rate issues

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that extends the SensorEventListener interface to listen for changes to the barometer, which I log in a logfile. Before I start logging, I prepend a system time in milliseconds (let's call this Millisecond Timestamp 1, or MT1), and after the logging is finished, I append another system timestamp in milliseconds (let's call this Millisecond Timestamp 2, or MT2).

The SensorEvent has its own timestamp (which I will call Nanosecond Timestamps, or NT), which I also log, between MT1 and MT2.

The problem is this: If the phone goes to sleep during the logging, the SensorEvent rate seems to no longer occur at the rate which I set (for example, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST). Furthermore, even though the SensorEvent timestamp is supposed to represent the nanoseconds of uptime since the phone has been rebooted, there are "missing" nanoseconds--the time gap between MT2 and MT1 is often twice or more that between NTN (where N is the number of samples) and NT1.

I've been able to sort of resolve this issue by using PowerManager.Wakelock(), but that results in my app being a huge power hog and seems like a really clumsy hack. Is there any other way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sensors are not guaranteed to work if the device goes to sleep, or even if the screen turns off (but the CPU has not necessarily yet powered down). The behavior is undocumented and definitely seems to vary by device.

Either settle for being "a huge power hog" or redesign your app to not require sensor readings except when the screen is on.

Sensors in Android are definitely designed to be used actively by foreground apps, not for long-term logging or monitoring purposes.

Comment: Well, the dichotomy of "settle for being "a huge power hog" or redesign your app to not require sensor readings except when the screen is on" is not strictly true--there are pedometer apps out there that somehow manage to avoid being huge power hogs AND work while the phone is asleep/its screen is turned off. I'm just not sure how they do it.

Comment: @Catherine: All I can do is point you at this issue where this topic has been discussed quite a bit: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708